# Convergence of Taylor series for $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=2$ by Lagrangian remainder?

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series for $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=2$ would look like this: $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{x-2}{2^2}+\frac{(x-2)^2}{2^3}-\frac{(x-2)^3}{2^4}+\frac{(x-2)^4}{2^5}...$

The radius of convergence of the Taylor series for this was $0<x<4$. It can be calculated just by observing the full expression of the $f(x)$ because, as you can see, it looks like an infinite geometric series. The common ratio, $|-\frac{x-2}{2}|$, has to be less than $1$.

Or you can do the trick of viewing geometric series as a taylor series.

$\frac{1}{x}$

$= \frac{1}{2+(x-2)}$

$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-2}{2}}$

$=\frac{1}{2}[1-\frac{x-2}{2}+\frac{(x-2)^2}{2^2}-\frac{(x-2)^3}{2^3}+...]$

$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x-2}{2^2}+\frac{(x-2)^2}{2^3}-\frac{(x-2)^3}{2^4}+...$

This is basically equal to the one obtained by regular expansion. But, what I want to do is to find out $0<x<4$ using the Lagrangian remainder. Here's what I've done below. I couldn't finish it. Please help.

Apparently, because the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)$ looks like $(-1)^nn!x^{-(n+1)}$, for an unknown value $ξ∈[2,x]$, the Lagrangian remainder, $|R|$, would be $|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!ξ^{-(n+2)}(x-2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}| = |\frac{1}{ξ}(\frac{x-2}{ξ})^{n+1}|$.

In order for this to approach $0$ as $n→∞$, $|\frac{x-2}{ξ}|<1$, which leads to $2-ξ<x<ξ+2$. But now what? I don't know what to do for the next step. Since $ξ∈[2,x]$, I could try this; at least you can always find $ξ=2$ when $x=2$, and by substituting $ξ=2$ to the inequality and get $0<x<4$? Then, what if $x≠2$? What should I do?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez how about now?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I found the answer. Basically it is a matter of getting $0<x<4$ when you have two conditions; $ξ∈[2,x]$ and $(2-ξ)<x<(2+ξ)$.

When you have $ξ∈[2,x]$, it means $-ξ∈[-x,-2]$ and then $(2-ξ)∈[2-x,0]$. Likewise, with $ξ∈[2,x]$, you get $(2+ξ)∈[4,x+2]$.

Let's look at $(2-ξ)<x<(2+ξ)$ again. $x$ lies at the right side of a number that is in $[2-x,0]$, and the left of a number in $[4,x+2]$, which means $0<x<4$.

Correct me if I'm wrong please.